# between ex4 and XFS which is better for large small files

Tags: ext4, xfs

Between EXT4 and XFS which file system is better when an application uses multiple threads to read/write large amount of small files on a SSD.
From what I read

> In general, Ext3 or Ext4 is better if an application uses a single
> read/write thread and small files, while XFS shines when an
> application uses multiple read/write threads and bigger files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Answer (score 1):

Both EXT4 and XFS are very fast in small file handling. EXT4 is faster for single thread operations, while XFS scales better when using multiple threads/cores.

You can read more in [RedHat documentation.](https://access.redhat.com/articles/3129891)